# How to change SAP WSDL tags?or Modify Webservice?

Tags: web-services, sapui5, abap

Does anyone know how to change the tags in the WSDL WebService?

What I am trying to do is to change

```
WSDLException (at
/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsp:Policy)
```

This error should be solved by changing the policy tag to standard?

Please let me know if anyone has information about this...

P.S the same question has also been asked at [SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12690612/how-to-change-wsdl-tagsor-modify-webservice.html)

Answer (score 0):

SAP versions support different policy tags. May be your wsdl has an unsupported policies. You can validate WSDL with report **RSSIDL_DESERIALIZE_DEMO** for getting more detail. You can remove policy tag but, in some some SAP version disabled username/password box in SOAMANAGER without policy element.

Comment: can you please show me how you remove that policy tag?also how is it possible that I can not create a binding service in quality ? the create binding service is disabled...

Comment: also what should I be looking for when I run that program?

Comment: You can remove it with any text editor (notepad, etc).  
You need to share more detail about quality system error. 
Run the report and check result or share with us.

Comment: but then how do I update the wsdl in the web service?please let me know

Comment: how can I share my program results?can you create a chat?

Comment: You don't need to upload wsdl. You can make changes on local file and use it. Stackoverflow is not a chat platform also we haven't got time for this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You cannot manipulate wsdl files which are generated by SAP system. If you change some settings of service in SOAMANAGER some tags will be changed.

Comment: but that is the problem,in soamanager in Kuali I cant create a binding service(the button create service is disabled) and nobody seem to have auth to create,however in development I can.I remove the policy make the tag without policy but I dont know how to transport it to Kuali?and even after changing the tag in development to no policy it till shows in the policy tag...Can you please show me where are these settings in SOAMANAGER to remove the tag and enable it for Kuali too.

Comment: What is Kuali? You cannot transport wsdl with request. It generated by system automatically. Policy tag can be removed by consumer side or send them edited WSDL file.

Comment: at first you say : change some settings of service in SOAMANAGER some tags will be changed then Policy tag can be removed by consumer side.Which one is true?Basically the policy tags can not be removed from the SOAMANAGER but the customer has to remove each then at each file?

Comment: I-Development K-Kuality(QA) and P-Production

Comment: All of them true. SOAMANAGER cannot be remove policy tag, only change/remove tags in policy because of choosed cofiguration. Which language try to import your WSDL files and getting error? If their platform giving error with policy tag, they must remove it. Because other platforms not giving error (for example .Net). If customer not accept removing solution may be you can develop custom service for removing tags in WSDL online. Check SAP wsdl generator class CL_SRT_WSP_WSDL_HANDLER_HTTP.